# How to install a plugin for QtWebKit

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, qtwebkit

I am running a Qt 4.5 commercial snapshot and want to use a plugin that I downloaded (it's a .so file) in my `QWebView`.  Is there a specific location where I need to place this file?  Can I grab it using the `QWebPluginFactory`?

Comment: A year later and I'm having the same problems. This time with the Adobe flash plugin.

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming the plugin here is the NPAPI plugin (e.g. Flash). Under X11, QtWebKit search several common directories for the plugin. For the complete list, see [the documentation on Netscape plugin support](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support).

In addition to that, you must enable plugin support via QWebSettings::. See the documentation for [WebAttribute::::PluginsEnabled](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum), either globally or for your particular QWebView only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a commercial client you should be demanding your money earned support directly from the trolltech(nokia) guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in the *standard library directories*? It should be picked up by the **linker** if it's in one of those directories.

For example:

```
/lib/
/usr/lib/
/usr/share/lib/
/usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: I did try that, but Qt doesn't pick it up.
I don't think this is something that has to be built into the code - when I want to add a plugin for Firefox, for example, I just drop the .so file in my .mozilla/plugins directory and Firefox picks it up at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking around in /usr/lib/qt4/plugins/ or somewhere similar yet?  I suppose that path will probably be where you have your 4.5 snapshot stuff compiled, but it should have options for putting in plugins for various things.