# How to make QtWebKit see Flash?

Tags: flash, qt, qtwebkit

What is the simplest way to make `QWebView` recognize and properly load Flash on the web page?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869/how-to-install-a-plugin-for-qtwebkit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348306/problem-with-qt-webkit-and-flash

Comment: @Flavius, thank you, this did it. I will still add the answer with the necessary code, to save someone 5 minutes of their time in case they will be googling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this can be achieved in just two lines (assuming flash is installed on target system, of course):

```
QWebSettings *settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setAttribute (QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Incase someone else is viewing this page to get the Plugin to work...you need to put the Flash plugin itself from Adobe into a proper directory (See QT website for this) first and make sure it is the right one(32/64bit) for your app(s) not necessarily your system...

Then see above answers if a code programmer...